# What's with this definition of ${\land}$?

Tags: logic

Let ${\implies}$ and ${\lnot}$ be primitives.

Let $p$ and $q$ be WFFs.

I've seen a formal definition of $p{\land}q$ as ${\lnot}(p{\implies}{\lnot}q)$.

How does this comply with the understanding of $p{\land}q$ as "$p$ is true and $q$ is true"?

I could understand it in the case of $p{\implies}q$, but what about $p{\lnot}{\implies}q$? In this case $q$ could still be false.

Comment: Dis you try a truth table?

Comment: It's easier to see that $p\to\lnot q$ is equivalent to $\lnot(p\wedge q)$.

Comment: When "$p$ is true and $q$ is true" we have that $(p \to ¬q)$ is $T \to F$, i.e. $F$, and thus $¬(p \to ¬q)$ is $T$.

Comment: '$\land$' and '$\neg$' are the usual primitives. '$\land$' is more intuitive than '$\implies$' with its informal suggestion of causal and temporal relations. It is even possible to use only a single primitive: the NAND-operator.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $\neg(p\implies q)=p\wedge \neg q$.

This is, in my opinion, fairly intuitive. If you wanted to prove "continuous implies differentiable"is wrong, you would need to find an example of a function that is continuous ($p$) and not differentiable ($\neg q$).

So $\neg (p \implies \neg q)=p\wedge \neg \neg q=p\wedge q$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to show $\lnot(p \Rightarrow \lnot q)$. To negate an implication $p \Rightarrow \lnot q$ we need to show that its premise $p$ is true and its conclusion $\lnot q$ is false, so we need to show exactly that $p$ and $q$ are both true. So the statement is equivalent to $p \land q$.

Comment: What if ${\lnot}q$ isn't a conclusion? What if one can't deduce whether $q$ is true or not from $p$? In that case, $q$ still can be false, and by this definition of $p{\land}q$, $p{\land}q$ is true and at the same time $p$ is true and $q$ is false.

Comment: It **is** the conclusion by definition. And the **only** way an implication can be false is if the left side is true while the right side is false.

Comment: How is it a conclusion by definition?

Comment: @user325165 in the statement is $p \Rightarrow q$ then $p$ is called the premise and $q$ the conclusion.

Comment: We have two WFFs, $1\,{\in}\,{\{1,2,3}\}$, which is called $p$ and ${\exists}A:({\forall}a\,{\in}\,A)a{\neq}a$, which is called $q$. How is one a conclusion of another?

Comment: @user325165  you're confusing syntax and semantics

Comment: I don't understand, explain.